# How to implement SSL on Apache 2.2

Tags: java, apache, ssl, configuration

Is there a step by step way to configure SSL on Apache 2.2. I have searched and tried a lot of things but the configuration is not working.

Comment: Off topic, and answered in the Apache documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these links. These might be useful for your case

http://extrimity.in/content/enable-ssl-or-https-ubuntu-1104-apache-2

http://wiki.vpslink.com/Enable_SSL_on_Apache2

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A95431_01/install/ssl.htm

**Step by step**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-12-04

http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/349